# Inequality involving Alternating Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Suppose a > $\frac{1}{2}$. I would like to show that:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r=0}^m (-1)^{m-r} {m \choose r} \frac{1}{q-r} \left(a^{q-r} -\frac{1}{2^{q-r}}\right) \geq 0. 
\end{equation}

Splitting my head on this. Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^m (-1)^{m-r} {m \choose r} \frac{1}{q-r} x^{q-r}$$
We need to show that $f(a)\geq f(\frac 1 2)$.
Then $$f^\prime(x)=\sum_{r=0}^m (-1)^{m-r} {m \choose r} x^{q-r-1}=x^{q-1}\left(\frac 1 x - 1\right)^m=x^{q-m-1}\left(1-x\right)^m$$
Thus $f^\prime(x)\geq0$ for $0\leq x \leq 1$. Consequently $f$ is non-decreasing and $f(a)\geq f(\frac 1 2)$ if $a\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks. Should that be (1-x)^m?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for catching this.

Comment: @StefanLafon More likely, $x^{q-m-1}(x-1)^m$. With $(1-x)^m$ the derivative is not always positive either.